# QGIS 3x Crop Content to Better Fit Page

Tags: qgis-print-layouts

I'm trying to print a map using the print manager.  The map I add to the page displays more or less as I'd like it to appear. It is set to zoom to the selected layer, which is a polygon of the area I'm interested in.  It displays in the viewer just fine.

If I go to the print and layout manager, set my page and paper size and add the map, the map content on the page includes a lot of area outside of the selected layer that doesn't appear on the view I'm adding the map from the map.  It does this if I have saved this view as a project as well as if I don't.

I'd like to zoom the content of the page to larger than the page and "crop" it to fit the page or something to display just the parts of the map I want to show.

I can see how to adjust the size of the page to fit the content, but, not the other way around.  The content I get when I add the map is not what it is I think I am adding.

Any suggestions???

Comment: What do you mean by "it is set to zoom to the selected layer"? Where did you find that option? That sounds like setting an Atlas map to zoom to the current atlas feature, but you didn't mention using an atlas.

Answer (score 1):

The scale of the print composer can be adjusted independently of the canvas scale.

Suppose I wanted to print the following:
[image]

But, after adding the map to the print composer I get:
[image]

I can:

**1) Use the *Select/Move item* [image] tool to select the *Map* item in the print composer.**

**2) Use the *Move item content* [image] tool to zoom using the scroll wheel.**

**3) Make fine adjustments by manually adjusting the print composer's *Scale* value.**

[image]

Final Product is close to the original canvas image:

[image]